# How do not move view when keyboard shows in React Native?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, scrollview

I have two elements in the screen. The first one is Scrollview with flex and the other is View with fixed height. When keyboard shows up View element goes up.

How to achieve element does not go up?

Ok, here is the code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Scrollview style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput />
    </Scrollview>
    <View style={{height: 24}}>
         Two buttons here...
    </View>
</View>
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Just want that two footer buttons do not go up when keyboard is shown.

Comment: are you using keyboardavoidingview>

Comment: use adjustResize in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Ok, but I am using expo.

Answer (score 9):

You can try following code. It may resolve your issue

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS == "ios" ? 0 : 20}
    enabled={Platform.OS === "ios" ? true : false}>

  <Text>Hello</Text>
  <Text>World</Text>

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Comment: `{Platform.OS === "ios" ? true : false}` can be replaced with `{Platform.OS === "ios"}`

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to achieve this :

KeyboardAvoidingView : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{flex: 1}} 
  behavior={'padding'} 
  keyboardVerticalOffset={65}>
    <FlatList .../>
    <TextInput ... />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Android :

Adjust keyboard using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`    settings in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
            ...
            >
     <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                ...
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                ...
                android:authorities="${applicationId}">
    </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` will make the Main activity view PAN move (i.e. be translated) **outside** of the screen! Use "adjustResize" if you want your components to resize (e.g. put one <View> with style={{flex:1}} and it will be the one that resizes when the keyboard is visible).