# Text box cover when keyboard open ios system in react native project

Tags: ios, react-native, textbox, keyboard

Text box cover when keyboard open ios system in react native,but working fine in android part.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:
KeyboardAvoidingView : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  style={{flex: 1}} 
  behavior={'padding'} 
  keyboardVerticalOffset={65}>
    <FlatList .../>
    <TextInput ... />
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

or for Android:
Adjust keyboard using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" settings in your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
            ...
            >
     <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                ...
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
                ...
                android:authorities="${applicationId}">
    </activity>
    </application>
```

refer: [How do not move view when keyboard shows in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58948751/how-do-not-move-view-when-keyboard-shows-in-react-native)